# addEventListener won't work? It should do something with onclick

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a form that after clicking on a radio button, I want a couple text inputs to appear.

That is not working. Nothing appears, the console does not say anything. After checking that the file does exists and it is called properly I did check other  JS in the same html document and it does work, so I guess is something wrong with the way I'm calling that function.

This is my html code:

```
          <label class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pagoMedioUtilizado" id="tarjeta" value="tarjeta" addEventListener="return avisoPago.tipoPago();">
            Tarjeta Crédito
          </label>

      <div class="form-group sr-only" id="bloqueOperacion">
        <label class="control-label">Código de la Operación</label>
          <input type="text" name="pagoCodigo" class="form-control" id="ticket" placeholder="Ingrese el número de Operación que está al pie del ticket">
      </div>
```

And here is the JS code:

```
var avisoPago = {
    //obtenemos el valor de email con this.email()
    fecha: function () {    return $('#fecha').val();   },  
    monto: function () {    return $('#monto').val();   },  
    cuentaOrigen: function () { return $('#cuentaOrigen').val();    },  
    sucursal: function () { return $('#sucursal').val();    },  
    ticket: function () {   return $('#ticket').val();  },  

    tipoPago: function() {
        if(document.getElementById('deposito').checked) {
            console.log('se depositó');
            $('#bloqueSucursal').removeClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueOperacion').removeClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueCuenta').addClass('sr-only');
        }else if(document.getElementById('transferencia').checked) {
            console.log('se transfirió');
            $('#bloqueCuenta').removeClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueSucursal').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueOperacion').addClass('sr-only');
        }else if(document.getElementById('tarjeta').checked) {
            console.log('se pagó con tarjeta');
            $('#bloqueCuenta').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueSucursal').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueOperacion').removeClass('sr-only');
        }else if(document.getElementById('efectivo').checked) {
            console.log('se pagó en efectivo');
            $('#bloqueCuenta').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueSucursal').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueOperacion').addClass('sr-only');
        }   
    },
```

So, as you can see, if I click the radio with id "tarjeta", the content of "bloqueOperacion should change classes. The sr-only is a class that hides content, so, the hidden stuff should appear after removing the class.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `return`? The function doesn't return anything.

Comment: remove `addEventListener` from html and add this in js `document.getElementById("tarjeta").addEventListener("click", function(){
    avisoPago.tipoPago()
});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`addEventListener` isn't an attribute, it's a function you call from JS.

But since you're using jQuery, you can use its shorter method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tarjeta").click(avisoPago.tipoPago);
});
```

Comment: Sigh, right. Can't assume the reader knows these obvious things.

Comment: I'm just starting with JS Thanks! Problem solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` is the wrong attribute name. Replace it with `onClick`

You confused the nonobtrusive js function with the HTML attribute.

Edit: what you want is

`onClick="avisoPago.tipoPago()"`

Comment: It was using onClick and it didn't work, that's why I changed it to addEventListener

Comment: @Rosamunda `addEventListener` is a function you call from Javascript, not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about everything else, but, by replacing `addEventListener` with `onclick`, removing the `return` from the `onclick`, changing tipoPago's `.getElementById` to `tarjeta`, the correct target, and adding a `}` to the end of the js object you provided, the console log is running properly.

```js
 var avisoPago = {
    //obtenemos el valor de email con this.email()
    fecha: function () {    return $('#fecha').val();   },  
    monto: function () {    return $('#monto').val();   },  
    cuentaOrigen: function () { return $('#cuentaOrigen').val();    },  
    sucursal: function () { return $('#sucursal').val();    },  
    ticket: function () {   return $('#ticket').val();  },  

    tipoPago: function() {
        if(document.getElementById('tarjeta').checked) {
            console.log('se depositó');
            $('#bloqueSucursal').removeClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueOperacion').removeClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueCuenta').addClass('sr-only');
        }else if(document.getElementById('transferencia').checked) {
            console.log('se transfirió');
            $('#bloqueCuenta').removeClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueSucursal').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueOperacion').addClass('sr-only');
        }else if(document.getElementById('tarjeta').checked) {
            console.log('se pagó con tarjeta');
            $('#bloqueCuenta').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueSucursal').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueOperacion').removeClass('sr-only');
        }else if(document.getElementById('efectivo').checked) {
            console.log('se pagó en efectivo');
            $('#bloqueCuenta').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueSucursal').addClass('sr-only');
            $('#bloqueOperacion').addClass('sr-only');
        }   
    },
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pagoMedioUtilizado" id="tarjeta" value="tarjeta" onclick="avisoPago.tipoPago();">
            Tarjeta Crédito
          </label>

      <div class="form-group sr-only" id="bloqueOperacion">
        <label class="control-label">Código de la Operación</label>
          <input type="text" name="pagoCodigo" class="form-control" id="ticket" placeholder="Ingrese el número de Operación que está al pie del ticket">
      </div>
```